# React router rendering twice and URL changes by dropping all query parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap, react-component

I am using `BrowserRouter` and `history.push` to navigate between pages. I want to traverse to a new page with query parameters entered in the first page.

i.e., in the homepage, there is a search bar where user enters some search string `abc`, and when the button is clicked, I want to redirect to another page `/search?q=abc`

What I observed is, the `/search?q=abc` is rendered properly once and then it automatically redirects to `/search?` dropping all the query parameters. I am not able to understand why is it rendering twice?

**Packages**

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component}  from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Jumbotron from "./component/Jumbotron";

const SearchPage = ({ match, location }) => {
  return (
      <p>
        <strong>Query Params: </strong>
        {location.search}
      </p>
  );
};

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
      <div className="d-flex flex-column">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Jumbotron/>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Route exact={true} path='/' render={HomePage}/>
          <Route exact path="/search" render={SearchPage} />
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Jumbotron.jsx** <- this is the first page containing search bar

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import history from "../utils/history";

class Jumbotron extends Component {

    handleSubmit = () => {
        history.push({
            pathname: '/search',
            search: '?q=' + this.state.query
        })
    };

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({query: e.target.value});
        console.log(e.target.value)
    };

    render() {
        return (<>
            <div className="d-flex jumbotron">
                <div className="align-self-center container mx-auto">
                    <br/>
                    <div>

                    </div>
                    <div className="align-self-center">
                        <form className="d-flex justify-content-center form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                            <input className="search-input col-md-6  mb-3 form-control"
                                   type="search"
                                   placeholder="Type the address here"
                                   aria-label="Search"
                                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                            <button className="search-btn col-md-1 mb-3 btn btn-primary"
                                    onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Search
                            </button>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Jumbotron);
```

**history.js**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

Here is an example with the above code that depicts the behavior:
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-fermat-60xzy

Comment: Please create a working example, using https://codesandbox.io for instance

Comment: @Dekel Added a link to an example. If you see in the sandbox, I can directly open a link `https://60xzy.csb.app/search?q=aaa` and that shows me the query params, but if I search the query params through the form field, it doesnt work.

Comment: I got this to work by wrapping your Jumbotron component in a `withRouter` and changing the `history.push()` to a `this.props.history.push`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 ways to solve your issue:

**First solution:**

- import `Router` not `BrowserRouter`
- pass your `history` that you have defined in `./history.js` to the `Router`. Like this `<Router history={history}>`
- Now `history.push({.....` should work as you expected.

**Second solution:**

- import `BrowserRouter`
- wrap the `Jumbotron` component with `withRouter`
- use `this.props.history.push(...)` instead of `history.push(...)`

**Working copy of your code(1st solution) is here:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/router-issue-page-refresh-after-search-hl849?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I also figured out the first approach. Just wondering, what is the recommended way here ? does BrowserRouter give something more than Router?

Comment: Custom `history` will provide you the flexibility of using `history` anywhere in your app be it components or general functions .....  With `BrowserRouter` , you will get history from `prop` out of the box which will be available to the route-components defined under the browser router. So the recommended way depends on your usecase. In many cases `BrowserRouter` would suffice.